# Position:Relative image that doesn't push nearby text?

Tags: html, css, image, position

Simple question: I need an image to appear in the middle of a paragraph of text, however, the image is slightly larger than the height of each line of the font, so it pushes open a horizontal "gap" in the text to make room for itself. To fix this, I could:

1) Shrink the image, so that it is not larger than the font.
2) Use Position:Absolute

But I don't want to shrink it any further, it is small enough already to "technically fit" between each line of text, except that it would need to use up a few pixels of the white area above and below the line of text it is in.

And I can't use position:absolute, because then the image's position would be in the top left corner of the window, instead of in the paragraph where I want it.

I thought perhaps I could put a dummy "placeholder" image of size 1 pixels into the paragraph. Then, use Position:Absolute on my real image, and continually set my real image to be at the same location where the dummy image is. I haven't researched to see if that is possible, but it seems a bit excessive for such a simple thing. Is there an easier way?

EDIT: I found that adding: margin:-20px; to the image's style works!!!

```
margin:-20px;
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/j7tLX/3/

Comment: Could your provide a jsFiddle or codepen so I can see the problem.

Comment: Might help if you show us what you have done. code or image for example... http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/

Comment: Here is what it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/j7tLX/2/ -- notice the image is pushing open a horizontal gap in the text above it, even though I've positioned the image down somewhat. I need a way to have the image where it is at the end of the paragraph, without it pushing the text above and to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

Images are block level elements if you want them to appear inline with the paragraphs. Do this.

```
img {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vertical-align: top`

http://jsfiddle.net/j7tLX/4/

See http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/